# Why content is dragging after removing scrollFlags `scroll`?

Tags: xml, android-layout, android-toolbar, android-coordinatorlayout

If remove at `app:layout_scrollFlags` value `scroll` in Toolbar , then content is moving to top. See screenshot

Here is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!--region Content-->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <!--region EmptyView-->
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="16dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/titleView"
                    fontPath="@string/font_semibold"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:textColor="#9b9b9b"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    tools:ignore="MissingPrefix"
                    tools:text="@string/error_view_internet_connection_title"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/messageView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:paddingStart="32dp"
                    android:paddingEnd="32dp"
                    android:textColor="#9b9b9b"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    tools:ignore="MissingPrefix"
                    tools:text="@string/error_view_internet_connection_message"
                    />

            </LinearLayout>
            <!--endregion-->

            <!--region List-->
            <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
                android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

                <RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:clipToPadding="false"
                    android:scrollbarSize="2dp"
                    android:scrollbars="vertical"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    tools:visibility="visible"/>

            </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
            <!--endregion-->

        </LinearLayout>
        <!--endregion-->

        <!--region Toolbar-->
        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:elevation="0dp"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_layout_behavior"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                style="?android:attr/toolbarStyle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#636363"
                android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
                app:elevation="0dp"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ToolbarStyle"
                app:theme="@style/ToolbarStyle"
                tools:ignore="NewApi"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
        <!--endregion-->

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <!--region BottomNavigation-->
    <com.aurelhubert.ahbottomnavigation.AHBottomNavigation
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:accentColor="#111232"
        app:inactiveColor="#111232"
        app:titleState="always_hide"/>
    <!--endregion-->

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

I remove the flag by func, and after that in UI it is shaking:

```
    public void setToolbarCollapsible(boolean collapsible) {
        int defaultFlags =
                AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.SCROLL_FLAG_SNAP
                | AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.SCROLL_FLAG_ENTER_ALWAYS
                | AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.SCROLL_FLAG_SCROLL;
        int none = 0;
//        //remove from toolbar
        Toolbar toolbar = getToolbar();
        if (toolbar == null) return;
        AppBarLayout.LayoutParams toolbarLayoutParams = (AppBarLayout.LayoutParams) toolbar.getLayoutParams();
        toolbarLayoutParams.setScrollFlags(collapsible ? defaultFlags : none);
        toolbar.setLayoutParams(toolbarLayoutParams);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If remove at `app:layout_scrollFlags` value `scroll` in Toolbar , then content is moving to top.

The content is shifting up because the height of the `LinearLayout` that wraps the `TextView` is changing height. As a result, `android:gravity="center"` specified on the `LinearLayout` computes a different vertical center.

The following layout is a simplified view of your layout for demonstration purposes.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/titleView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/error_view_internet_connection_title"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:title="Toolbar" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here is the layout inspector view of this layout showing the height of the `LinearLayout` with and without the scroll flag set.

[image]

Without the scroll flag set, the height of the `LinearLayout` that wraps the `TextViews` is smaller by the height of the `Toolbar`. This makes sense since the `LinearLayout`is `match_parent` it must fit. With the scroll flag set, the `LinearLayout` can be taller since it can scroll and does not have to fit within the screen. In fact, it is as tall as the screen but shifted below the toolbar.

You can do a quick test about whether this is the case or not but replacing `android:gravity="center"` with a top margin.

> I remove the flag by func, and after that in UI it is shaking

I think that I have seen this behavior before, but I don't recall the reason for it. Since `CoordinatorLayout` is so dynamic, it may be some kind of oscillation in the layout due to some layout ambiguity. This is, however, nothing more than  guess. If you clean up your layout a little and consider why you are manipulating the scroll flag (Is there another way?), you may be able to resolve the problem.

Short of that, a small runnable project that demonstrates the jitter problem may be a helpful thing to post.